# C++ form freezes during while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, forms, while-loop, bluetooth

I'm having trouble with my Form in c++. The form crashes because of my while loop. The while loop is needed for checking the output it receives from an external device. it is actually a log application which continuously prints the data it receives from the device, a real-time log. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I have 1 .cpp and 1 header file. The header file only includes the method for running the form. In the .cpp file, the function which performs the getting and checking of file is in the "Connect" button event. I also have a disconnect button which obviously disconnects the connection between the form and external device. I'm connecting it via bluetooth. It perfectly receives the output and exactly prints what it needs to print. The only problem is that, I cannot click the disconnect button anymore because it freezes.

This is my code for the GetBluetoothOutput:

```
void GetBluetoothOutput(HANDLE btSerial)
        {
            std::map<char, std::string> map = {
                { 'A', "Unit is moving forward at high speed." },
                { 'B', "Unit is moving forward at medium speed." },
                { 'C', "Unit is moving forward at low speed." },
                { 'D', "Unit is moving backward." },
                { 'E', "Turn Left." }};

            int previous = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
            BYTE Byte;
            DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
            int retVal;

            SetCommMask(btSerial, EV_RXCHAR); //receive character event
            WaitCommEvent(btSerial, &dwCommModemStatus, 0); //wait for character

            if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR)
            {
                ReadFile(btSerial, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0); //read 1
                retVal = Byte;
            }

            if (previous != retVal)
            {
                previous = retVal;
                char *getOutput;
                getOutput = (char*)&retVal;
                auto find = map.find(*getOutput);
                if (find != map.end())
                {
                    std::string description = find->second;
                    m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add(gcnew String(description.c_str()));
                }
                else
                {
                    m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("Unknown input sent from bluetooth.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add(".............");
            }
            m_LogDisplayBox->Update();
        }
    }
```

This is my code for the Connect button:

```
private: System::Void ConnectBtnEvent(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    m_DisconnectButton->Enabled = true;
    m_ConnectButton->Enabled = false;

    int m_Port = m_PortComboBox->SelectedIndex;
    int m_BaudRate = m_BaudRateComboBox->SelectedIndex;
    int data = m_DataComboBox->SelectedIndex;
    int parity = m_ParityComboBox->SelectedIndex;
    int stop = m_StopComboBox->SelectedIndex;
    int flowControl = m_FlowControlComboBox->SelectedIndex;

    switch (m_BaudRate)
    {
    case 0:
        m_BaudRate = CBR_110;
        break;
    case 1:
        m_BaudRate = CBR_300;
        break;
    case 2:
        m_BaudRate = CBR_600;
        break;
    default:
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("No \"Baud Rate\" selected.");
    }

    switch (data)
    {
    case 0:
        data = 7;
        break;
    case 1:
        data = 8;
        break;
    default:
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("No \"Data\" selected.");
    }

    switch (parity)
    {
    case 0:
        parity = NOPARITY;
        break;
    case 1:
        parity = ODDPARITY;
        break;
    case 2:
        parity = EVENPARITY;
        break;
    case 3:
        parity = MARKPARITY;
        break;
    case 4:
        parity = SPACEPARITY;
        break;
    default:
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("No \"Parity\" selected.");

    }

    switch (stop)
    {
    case 0:
        stop = ONESTOPBIT;
        break;
    case 1:
        stop = ONE5STOPBITS;
        break;
    case 2:
        stop = TWOSTOPBITS;
    default:
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("No \"Stop\" selected.");
    }

    HANDLE btSerial = BluetoothInit(m_Port, m_BaudRate, data, stop, parity);

    if (isConnected){
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("Connection Successful!");
        GetBluetoothOutput(btSerial); //This is the method which has the while-loop for continuously reading the outputs from bluetooth.
    }
    else{
        m_LogDisplayBox->Items->Add("Connection Unsuccessful");
        m_DisconnectButton->Enabled = false;
        m_ConnectButton->Enabled = true;
    }

}
```

I've read that 1 solution is to use multithreading. Does anyone can give other solutions than multithreading because I'm not very familiar with threads. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in an infinite Loop - while(1) will never come out of that loop, you need to do something like While(isConnected) and then have some way of disconnecting while in the loop.

Maybe checking inside of the while loop if the disconnect button has been clicked will help

Comment: i can't click the disconnect button because when i run the program, it continues to accept inputs (which works properly) but freezes the whole form. the display updates but i can't use scroll down.

Comment: it freeze because while(1) means it will never come out of that loop, so once you call that loop no other code after will run, nothing else is reachable, so you will need to redesign how that loop works

Answer (score 0):

Try using another condition. `while (1)`  is an infinite loop.